# How to construct complete tree from level order traversal

Tags: c++, c

---

How to construct complete tree from level order traversal?

total =7 nodes

20,8,22,4,12,-1,-1 to

```
    20
   /  \
  8    22
 / \   / \
4  12 -1  -1
```

you may have dummy nodes with -1 in binary tree too

construct tree from this level order 
Is this not possible?

Comment: `LeftChildIndex = 2 * ParentIndex` and `RightChildIndex = 2 * ParentIndex + 1` (using 1-indexing).

Comment: Then you should read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and post [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we are no "gimme teh codez" site! Time to sit down and do your homework!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a simple insertion to me.
If you have the values of the nodes in the order you specified just run a recursive insertion.

```
void insert(node_t **root, int val)
{
      if (*root == NULL) {
            *root = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
            *root->val   = val;
            *root->left  = NULL;
            *root->right = NULL;
       } else if ((*root)->val >= val) {
            insert(&(*root)->left, val);
       } else {
            insert(&(*root)->right, val);
       }
 }
```

In you're main function you could call it as follows:

```
int main (void)
{
     node_t *root = NULL;
     // call this with each value in
     insert(&root, <your value>);
 }
```

- you'll of course need to define a node_t struct, but you get the gist
- This code may or may not compile, I've typed it on my phone

Answer (score -2):

First you should find the pivot values. then would you sorted the elements(any sorting algorithm will b using.better way to bubble sort) after you performing those operations.